# Solidity group addresses with a name. Eg: Whats app groups

Tags: solidity, contract-development, solidity-0.5.x

I want to create a squad(group) which consists of a group addresses.
Like Squad XYZ consists of Addr1 with name 'A',Addr2 with Name 'B', Addr3 with name 'C'.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.9;

contract Squads{

    struct squadMemberInfo{
        string memberName;
        address memberAddress;
    }
    struct squadInfo{
        string squadName;
         squadMemberInfo[] squadMembers;
    }
    squadInfo[] public SI;
    squadMemberInfo[] public SMI;
    //Function to create a Squad/Group and name that group
    function createSquad(address[] memory _addressesToBeGrouped,string memory _squadName) public returns(string memory isCreated){
        //Yet to be coded
    }
    //Function to add Members to an existing Squad
    function addMember(string memory _squadName,address _memberAddress, string memory _memberName) public returns(bool isAdded){
        squadMemberInfo memory squadMember = squadMemberInfo(_memberName,_memberAddress);
        SMI.push(squadMember);
        squadInfo memory squadInformation = squadInfo(_squadName,SMI);
        SI.push(squadInformation);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I want make `squadMemberInfo[] public SMI;` as a local variable inside function `addMember` so that the function could return array of `squadMemberInfo[]`. I can directly use this return array and feed the `struct squadInfo`.

Also I am a bit confused how could I achieve this. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [mappings](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.10/types.html#mapping-types). Think they can give you a solution. I see your struct `squadInfo` already has the `squadMembers` array so that should achieve the functionality you're looking for of grouping addresses. If you want to return those addresses, you can set up a getter function which looks up a squad and returns its members, or alternatively, you could give unique IDs to each squad and store squad members in a `mapping(uint => address[]) squadMembers`. As for giving each address a name, you can either use a mapping inside of your struct, to assign names within that context only, or use a global mapping so that names are transferrable accross squads.

This mapping would look like this: `mapping(address => string) addressName`.

To set values for mappings just use `addressName[ADDRESS HERE] = "name";`.

Essentially, a lot of what you're doing can be done just with arrays but might add too much complexity. You should really read up on mappings because I think they'll really help you!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yakko majuri. That really helped me in getting things done. I am using mapping now which may the way a bit simpler.

Comment: Happy to have helped @AbdulMuqeem!